# Angular JS text highlighter directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted a directive to highlight text in an element based on a search string.

Most of the available solutions use a filter instead of a directive and are used like this:

```
<div ng-html-bind-unsafe="This is the contents for this div | highlight:highlightText"></div>
```

Here is an [example](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/highlight)

I would rather use a directive than a filter because I don't like the idea of having to put the content of an element in the ng-html-bind attribute. I feel like an element's contents should be inside of it.

Anyway, I wrote I directive for this but was wondering if there is a better way to write it. I feel like it is not the most efficient of methods. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NK4H2/). Notice that text within the `<code>` element is not highlighted. This is due to .contents() only returning the direct children and text nodes of the element. This behaviour is fine unless there is a very simple way to recurse through the contents of each child element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't very clear. I'm just asking for confirmation that this is an acceptable way to go about doing this and if not, then whether any experienced angular developers can provide me with a more efficient / correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

For traversing through the contents of each child elements, you can use recursion. Put the code for add highlighters and remove highlighterd into a function and call these functions for each child element.

.contents() returns a Jquery object. Convert it to an angular element if `node.nodeType === 1` and call contents() on it again.

```
        /*Function to add Highlighters*/
        scope.addHighlight = function (elm, value) {
            angular.forEach(elm.contents(), function (node) {
                if (node.nodeType === 3 && scope.needle.test(node.nodeValue)) {
                    node = angular.element(node);
                    node.after(node[0].nodeValue.replace(scope.needle, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>')).remove();

                } else if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                    node = angular.element(node);
                    if (node.contents().length > 0) scope.addHighlight(node, value);
                }
            });
        }
        /*Function to remove current Highlighters*/
        scope.removeHighlight = function (elm, value) {
            angular.forEach(elm.contents(), function (node) {
                nodetype = node.nodeType;
                node = angular.element(node);
                if (node[0].nodeName === 'SPAN' && node.hasClass('highlight')) {
                    node.after(node.html()).remove();
                    elm[0].normalize();
                }

                if (node.children().length > 0 && nodetype === 1) scope.removeHighlight(node, value);

            });
        }
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NK4H2/2/).